# How to edit a file in two viewports in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I want to compare two parts of a very long file and edit them at the same time.
Can I open two viewports of the same file, and roll one to the upper part, the other to the lower part?
Should one file only have one viewport?
My edition is 3.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `Right Click` on an opened tab
2. `Split Vertically` or `Horizontally.`

Simple as that.